# Screen capture using PhantomJS web server module

Tags: http, phantomjs

I have a PhantomJS web server module running on localhost:8082. I would like to send an HTTP request that opens a website and screen captures it. It is my understanding that I can add certain parameters (such as `address` or `output`) to the request. Unfortunately, I cannot find a list of accepted parameters as the [documentation of the web server module](http://phantomjs.org/api/webserver/) is rather sparse. Additionally, I am not sending the request from a Javascript environment and therefore cannot `require` a reference to the webserver module (as recommended by the docs).

My idea is to send an HTTP request that looks something like this:

```
GET http://127.0.0.1:8082?open=http://www.google.com&output=result.png
```

Is something like this possible using PhantomJS' web server module? How would a proper request look like?

Comment: Sure, that would be possible. Also please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I have edited the question and provided more information. I think I just need to be pointed into the right direction as I am not sure if I properly understand the concept of PhantomJS.

Comment: Much better, I will take a look at it later if nobody else will answer.

Comment: Have you seen this [example](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/blob/master/examples/server.js)? There are no accepted parameters, it can be whatever you want. You need to get them yourself from the request and do what you need with them.